# Python. KeyError with steam api

Tags: python

When using python and steam api trying to get a certain value using data = profile['gameextrainfo'] profile has the value of the API which is.

```
d = {"response":
        {"players":[
            {"steamid":"76561199446676130",
            "communityvisibilitystate":3,
            "profilestate":1,
            "personaname":"S7 WatchDog",
            "profileurl":"https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561199446676130/",
            "avatar":"https://avatars.akamai.steamstatic.com/415bd0e2ddd5d8e99309eec6d7a2566cbb09022d.jpg","avatarmedium":"https://avatars.akamai.steamstatic.com/415bd0e2ddd5d8e99309eec6d7a2566cbb09022d_medium.jpg","avatarfull":"https://avatars.akamai.steamstatic.com/415bd0e2ddd5d8e99309eec6d7a2566cbb09022d_full.jpg",
            "avatarhash":"415bd0e2ddd5d8e99309eec6d7a2566cbb09022d",
            "personastate":1,
            "primaryclanid":"103582791429521408",
            "timecreated":1671522419,
            "personastateflags":0,
            "gameextrainfo":"Counter-Strike: Global Offensive",
            "gameid":"730"}]
        }
    }
```

I cannot seem to filter out any key. I've tried all of them and python just fails to find them. Any ideas

Tried all keys. Tried using requests python module

Comment: You certainly need to use `data = profile['response']['players'][0]['gameextrainfo']`

Comment: The code defines a dictionary named `d`.  What is `profile`?

Answer (score -1):

You could use the json module to parse the response and access the individual data points. For example:

```
import json 
data = json.loads(profile) 
gameextrainfo = data['response']['players'][0]['gameextrainfo'] 
print(gameextrainfo)
```